# How can multiple rows be concatenated into one in Oracle without creating a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, string-aggregation

How can I achieve the following in oracle without creating a stored procedure?

Data Set:

```
question_id    element_id
1              7
1              8
2              9
3              10
3              11
3              12
```

Desired Result:

```
question_id    element_id
1              7,8
2              9
3              10,11,12
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are many way to do the string aggregation, but the easiest is a user defined function.  [Try this for a way that does not require a function.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php)  As a note, there is no simple way without the function.

This is the shortest route without a custom function: (it uses the ROW_NUMBER() and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH functions )

```
SELECT questionid,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(elementid,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS elements
FROM   (SELECT questionid,
               elementid,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY questionid ORDER BY elementid) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY questionid ORDER BY elementid) -1 AS prev
        FROM   emp)
GROUP BY questionid
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND questionid = PRIOR questionid
START WITH curr = 1;
```

Comment: Works great! ROW_NUMBER() is what I was missing to make sys_connect_by_path work for me.

Comment: Note that when this technique is applied to concatenate a field whose value may contain the separator, the following error is thrown: `ORA-30004: when using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function, cannot have separator as part of column value.`... And if the concatenated value happens to exceed the max length of 4000 bytes, you'd get the error: `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.`

Answer (score 150):

From Oracle 11gR2, the [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) clause should do the trick:

```
SELECT question_id,
       LISTAGG(element_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY element_id)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Beware if the resulting string is too big (more than 4000 chars for a VARCHAR2, for instance): from version 12cR2, we can use [ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE/ERROR](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/listagg-function-enhancements-12cr2) to deal with this issue.

Comment: As a side note, we can know the database version by querying the table `v$version` or `product_component_version`. 11.2 indicates 11gR2.

Comment: at any rate it helped me

Comment: Using it for a long time and this is as simple as it gets.

Comment: Is this missing `GROUP BY question_id`  ?

Answer (score 45):

(**WARNING** - `WM_CONCAT` is an unsupported function that was removed in version 12c. Unless you're using a very old database, you should avoid this function.)

---

Easy:

```
SELECT question_id, wm_concat(element_id) as elements
FROM   questions
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Pesonally tested on 10g ;-)

From http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php

Comment: Note though that wm_concat is an undocumented function. So you might want to think twice before using this in production code.

Comment: Very cool. Works for me too, but I'll need to make sure this function is available in our production environment.

Comment: I get Error -->   ORA-00904  WM_CONCAT : Invalid Identifier

Comment: `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small` if the concatenated value happens to exceed the max length of 4000 bytes.

Comment: i used to use wmsys.wm_concat(...) for most of my quick and dirty jobs in oracle 11g (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production)

Comment: You saved my time and teach me a good lesson. Thank you

Comment: This is simple solution than listagg function

Comment: Worked perfectly on my production 10g 10.2.0.4.0. Great answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This OTN-thread contains several ways to do string aggregation, including a performance comparison: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=1819487#1819487