# how to insert multiple rows from a source table into a single row in target table using cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, string-aggregation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can multiple rows be concatenated into one in Oracle without creating a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076011/how-can-multiple-rows-be-concatenated-into-one-in-oracle-without-creating-a-store)

```
create table pr_info(
   pr_ref varchar2(10),
   pr_text varchar2(3), 
   pr_key varchar2(12)
)
```

This table contains the data in the following format

```
pr_ref pr_text  pr_key
a1     abc      qwertyui01 
a1     def      qwertyui02
b1     aaa      zxcvbnmj01
b1     bbb      zxcvbnmj02
b1     ccc      zxcvbnmj03
```

That is if the pr_text is more than 3 characters long then the record is split and placed in a new record with same pr_ref but different pr_key(in this case the first 8 characters will remain the same but the last two character will signify the sequence of the record)

So now i need to put the data of this table into a new table which has the following sprecification

```
create table pv_cus(pv_ref vrachar2(10),pv_text varchar2(100))
```

So basically i need to concatenate the rows belonging to same person from the source table and put it in one row in target table.

```
pv_ref  pv_text    
a1      abc,def    
b1      aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

Procedural approach

```
DECLARE

  type pv_ref_t is TABLE of pv_cus.pv_ref%type;
  type pv_text_t is TABLE of pv_cus.pv_text%type;
  v_pv_ref_tab pv_ref_t;
  v_pv_text_tab pv_text_t;
  v_last_pr_ref  pr_info.pr_ref%type;
BEGIN
  v_pv_ref_tab := pv_ref_t();
  v_pv_text_tab := pv_text_t();

  FOR rec in (SELECT pr_ref, pr_text FROM pr_info order by  pr_ref, pr_key)
  LOOP
    IF v_last_pr_ref IS NULL
    OR v_last_pr_ref != rec.pr_ref
    THEN
      v_last_pr_ref := rec.pr_ref;
      v_pv_ref_tab.extend(1);
      v_pv_text_tab.extend(1);
      v_pv_ref_tab(v_pv_ref_tab.last) := rec.pr_ref;
      v_pv_text_tab(v_pv_text_tab.last) := rec.pr_text;
    ELSE
      -- tbd: check length of v_pv_text_tab(v_pv_text_tab.last)
      v_pv_text_tab(v_pv_text_tab.last) := v_pv_text_tab(v_pv_text_tab.last) || ',' || rec.pr_text;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  FORALL  i in 1..v_pv_ref_tab.last
    INSERT INTO pv_cus (pv_ref, pv_text) VALUES(v_pv_ref_tab(i), v_pv_text_tab(i))
  ;
END;
/
```