# Bring only one line in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, subquery

I'm am doing a SELECT query, that bring back a car, and some of its pieces it need to repair.

So I'm doing linke this :

```
SELECT id_car, concat((select pi.name_piece from t_piece pi LEFT JOIN t_piece_car pc on pc.id_piece = pi.id_piece where pc.id_car = 222), ',') as listPiece
from car 
where id_car = 222
```

piece contains all possible pieces.
piece_car is a link between my car and piece. So it contains all pieces my car needs.

The problem here is, the subquery bring more than one line. 
I tried to concat inside the subquery, but nothing better.
My car need 3 pieces, so it bring back 3 lines.
I have to bring back one line, like this :

'piece1, piece2, piece3' as listPiece

But I always got 3 lines.

**This is the subQuery that need to bring back only one line, with a concat of all the pieces names of my car, not the principal query.**

**UPDATE : Finally found another question here :**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1076237/1439453

Considering, that my answer is not the same that in this question, I don't really know if it's needed to let this question open, but necessary to let exists.

How can I do this.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using 11g use `LISTAGG()` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Not in Oracle @huMptyduMpty.

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/04/05/group_concat-in-oracle-10g/

Comment: @peterm I'm using 10g, but this is a start for me.

Comment: @Zaphod Try `WM_CONCAT()` then

Comment: @peterm Yes, just found out `WM_CONCAT()` , in another question. Add a link in my update. Guess I will add a space between two elements later in t he code.