# Concatenating text data in a column using SQL

Tags: sql, infomaker

Does anyone know how to concatenate all the values of a column in a query using SQL only? I know that there are ways using database specific tools such as pivot, but I don't think I have access to something like that in infomaker.

I am using infomaker to produce labels for sample bottles. The bottles can be analysed for more than one thing. If I join the bottle and analysis tables I get several rows per bottle which results in multiple labels, so I was hoping to concatenate all the values for the analysis using SQL and then use a computed value based on this to add something useful to the label. I can only use 1 transaction based on a select query to do this.

Adding additional tables or columns to the database would be highly discouraged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6427807/743868

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: @scaisEdge I am using oracle, but through a connection from infomaker.

Comment: @AndrewJenkins I need to concatenate the values for multiple rows of 1 column, rather than multiple columns of 1 row,

Comment: Ah, try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12421460/743868

Answer (score 0):

In some oracle version  you can use  wm_concat

```
SELECT field1, wm_concat(field2) FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY field2;
```

otherwise you can use listagg