# SQL to concatenate all Query rows into one row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have seen the following questions but can't get them to work for what I'm looking for.

[How can multiple rows be concatenated into one in Oracle without creating a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076011/how-can-multiple-rows-be-concatenated-into-one-in-oracle-without-creating-a-stor)

[SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

I am using Oracle and would like the solution not to have pl-Sql.

I'm trying to get the query to look as so with a possible new line per each row and delimited with a | or comma :

Data Set:

```
question_id    element_message    date
--------------------------------------------
1              hello              10/10/19
2              goodbye            11/11/19
```

Desired one row query result:

```
1 | hello  | 10/10/19 --new line added in query(if possible)
2 | goodbye| 11/11/19
```

And if new line in query isn't possible:

Desired result:

```
1 | hello  | 10/10/19 | 2 | goodbye| 11/11/19 |
```

*EDIT
To to clarify why I am using this. I am using a tool called Geneos with has a row by row limitation in terms of triggering an email. So this is a hack to trigger one email for all the rows per that day.

Comment: Why do you want unrelated data together in a single row?

Comment: We are using a tool called Geneos and it can only render data on a row by row basis.

Comment: You may modify the `LISTAGG` query in one of the answers in the link you shared and use the delimiter as `chr(10)`( represents a newline) separating each line instead of a comma. But, do note that the overall length after  concatenation can't exceed 4000 characters. There are other aggregation techniques discussed [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)  to achieve the same which may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want a one row query if you want each row to be printed on a different line?

If you just wan to run a query that returns your data with no header or page separator use this:

```
set pagesize 0
select  question_id || '|' || element_message || '|' || date from your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server solution :You can solve it using** `self join` **like below:**

```
select top 1 CONCAT(d1.question_id, ' | ', d1.element_message, ' | ', d1.date, 
'|' d2.question_id, ' | ', d2.element_message, ' | ', d2.date) 
from data d1 join data d2 on (d1.question_id < d2.question_id and)
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Oracle, so an SQL server solution isn't useful to the OP.

Comment: you can use row num for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT CONCAT(question_id, ' | ', element_message, ' | ', date) FROM Data
```

Comment: The `CONCAT` function in Oracle can take only 2 arguments.