# Regular expression to remove suffix from last name

Tags: regex, plsql

I need to create a regular expression to remove suffixes from the last name. suppose the last name is like the below tables. I need this regex for pl/sql(oracle). Thank you in advance.

```
Input string   -> expected output

    SMITH      -> SMITH
    SMITH JR.  -> SMITH
    SMITH ,JR  -> SMITH
    SMITH JR I -> SMITH
    SMITH /SR  -> SMITH
    SMITH S    -> SMITH S ( S is not present in the predefined suffix list)
```

Predefined list includes JR, SR, I II, III ,IV, V

Comment: So, there's a list of predefined suffixes? Does it mean that you have to remove everything that's in that list, and leave everything else? If so, I guess you should share that list with us.

Comment: Too bad, other members voted to close the question so I can't post query which (kind of) returns result you wanted. I'm not sure whether it'll be reopened or not, but - if you posted a new question, I'll post that query so that you could see whether it helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate database table, name SUFFIXES, to hold the list of suffixes.

```sql
create table SUFFIXES (SUFFIX varchar2(5))
```

I created another database table to hold the surnames.

```sql
create table SURNAMES (SURNAME varchar2(20))
```

Use [LISTAGG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076011/how-can-multiple-rows-be-concatenated-into-one-in-oracle-without-creating-a-stor) to get a regular expression containing all the suffixes with alternation.

```sql
select listagg(SUFFIX, '|') from SUFFIXES
```

Use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) to first replace unwanted punctuation.

```sql
select regexp_replace(SURNAME, ',|/') from SURNAMES
```

Note that in the sample data in your question there is only comma (',') and forward slash ('/').

Use another REGEXP_REPLACE on the result of the above to then remove the suffixes.

```sql
select regexp_replace((regexp_replace(SURNAME, ',|/')), (select listagg(SUFFIX,'|') from SUFFIXES)) as RESULT
  from SURNAMES
 where SURNAME like ('SMITH%')
```

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3zAQ2UcS).

By the way – not that it affects the question or answer – according to [Guide to Writing Men's Names with Suffixes](https://emilypost.com/advice/mens-names-and-titles), if grandfather, father and son all have the same name, then the grandfather's suffix is **Sr**, the father's suffix is **Jr** and the son's suffix is **III**. In other words there is no **I** suffix nor is there a **II** suffix.